# Help me to sketch the region according to the question.

Tags: integration, volume

I encountered this question. However, I did not understand the solution given by the books (on sketching parts)

This is the question:
**Find the volume of the solid using triple integral, where the solid bounded ABOVE by plane 2x+3y+z=6 and BELOW by plane z=1 in the first octant.**

This is the solution:
[region sketch according to the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZpOy.jpg)

please help me understand how the shaded region turned out like this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shaded region is defined by the intersections of the planes $2x+3y+z=6$, z=1, x=0, and y=0.

The top point of the prism is found by setting $x=0$ and $y=0$, solving $2x+3y+z=6$ for the z-intercept, giving us $z=6$.

The lower left most point in the diagram is found by setting $z=1$ and $y=0$, solving $2x+3y+z=6$ for $x$, which yields $x=\frac{5}{2}$ and the point $(\frac{5}{2},0,1)$.

The right most point is similar, set $z=1$ and $x=0$ and solve $2x+3y+z=6$ for $y$ giving $y=\frac{5}{3}$ which means our next point is $(0,\frac{5}{3}, 1)$

The center rear point is the point where the plane $z=1$ intersects with the z-axis, so $(0,0,1)$

Comment: thank you for the explanation. however, i am confused with the word below by plane z=1 in the question, because my understanding from the word below is that the shaded region should be below plane z=1. however in the answer given, the shaded region is above the plane z=1.

Comment: Ahh, okay...  So what it sounds like to me is a confusion about the term bounded.  When we say bounded we are talking about the barrier that is formed, or the outside walls.  So an analogy would be that when we say bounded below, it is essentially like saying the floor is below you in a room, and saying bounded above is like the ceiling being above you. It seems that you might be thinking about this more like you being above the floor.   So bounded below means that $z=1$ is the bottom of the prism, and bounded above means that  $2x+3y+z=6$ is the top.

Comment: thank you so much! that is the best explanation, thank you!